# How to Capture Console Output from CSharpScript Evaluation

Tags: c#, console, eval

```cs
var code = "return 1 + 2"; 
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(code, _scriptOptions);

// "result" is 3.
```

```cs
var code = "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello World\");"; 
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(code, _scriptOptions);

// "result" is null
```

In the second example, the `Console.WriteLine()` is evaluated and literally written to console. How can evaluate so it returns the string instead?

Comment: Does the output get printed in your program's output window?

Comment: Yes @RowanRadosav-McRae

Comment: In that case, a hackish solution would be to intercept the console output while running the function. I'll try and figure out a proper solution but this should work in the meantime